# Printers.conf permanent changes

Tags: networking, printing, password

After upgrading to MATE 18.04 on my ASUS X550LA, I cannot use my printer because I am always asked for User name  and Password. I've tried every password/name combination on my computer with no success.

I've tried many suggested fixes from various sources including 'commenting out' the Authentication line (AuthInfoRequired) in my *printers.conf* and *printers.conf.O* files which seems to be the most logical.

However I am still asked for authentication and when checking I find the both .conf files have been restored to the original that is:-

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v2.2.7
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<DefaultPrinter Canon-MP480>
UUID urn:uuid:e4d53bd0-7195-3389-4abe-ba55ea67dd44

AuthInfoRequired username,password

Info Canon MP480

MakeModel Canon MP480 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13
```

(These are only the first few lines)

The printer is networked with a Windows 10 desktop, but up to the recent upgrade I could connect by WI-FI without the need for a password. File sharing and 'no password' are selected on the Windows machine. I tried connecting the printer directly to the ASUS via USB, but was still asked for authentication.

I feel changing the printers.conf file would solve the problem, but I'd appreciate somebody helping me with making the changes permanent please. Also why are there two files with  different names with what appears to be identical content?

This replaces a recent question I had posted on this that I have deleted as being too imprecise.

Hal_v

My recent attempt at printing resulted in the "job" being held for Authentication, opening the attributes gave the following:-[image]
I appreciate all the help. Hal_v

Comment: if you go to the PRINTERS folder; delete the icon for the MP480; and click on NEW; and start again: does the same issue recur? this wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu talks of networked printing

Comment: Yes I've tried that and the problem persists, thanks for the suggestion though. Hal._v

Comment: In a fiurther attempt to locate the problem I connected the printer direct via USB. MATE installed the printer but when trying to "Print test page"  it stopped halfway through. I'd really appreciate some help with this. Hal_v

Comment: again; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu have a look at the diagram at the top: from Ubuntu; to a windows server = samba

Comment: so this sub-section https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Printing_from_Ubuntu says how to print from ubuntu to windows serve

Comment: Thanks pdc, I've worked through these options but still am asked for Authentication. I've taken a snapshot of the job attributes in the print queue, which says "Held for authentication", but I don 't know how to attach it to this comment. Can you help there also please. Hal.

Comment: you can add snapshots in your top answer I think; there should be an option there .. somewhere .. google  may help

Comment: this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151863/print-job-held-for-authentication?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa discusses the issue; and has 2 possible solutions

Comment: Thank you once again @pdc, I tried changing the smb.conf as one of the answers in the Stack Exchange link suggested, still no luck, I'm afraid I am still being asked for Authentication. Hal_v

Comment: Further update: I installed the two suggested utilities from the other answer and even after a reboot I am still required to Authentic. I really believe if I could make a"Permanent" change to the printers.conf the problem would disappear, however any changes I make seem to always be over -written. Any further suggestions will be appreciated and I'll try and keep you up to date. Thanks again Hal_v